# Reading windows log events generates new log event. How to prevent this?

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

I'm using .Net feature to read events from windows event log from remote machine, like this:

```
var eventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs(Hostname);
var collection = eventLogs[0].Entries;

 foreach (var item in collection)
 {
     //Do something
 }
```

But this generates a lot of new SuccessAudit events in event log. Does anybody know how to prevent this new events appear in event log?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting at the exact eventlog / application name that you have intended instead of a collection of all the events..

Comment: I need to read all events for all applications and standard ones: System, Security, etc.

Comment: here is a link that you may also want to look at that may or may not help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LogString.aspx

Answer (score 1):

On my particular system I am not sure that I can avoid this.  That said, I can easily avoid reading that particular event log if that is the problem.  I can choose to write or read from a particular log and just avoid the 'Security' log.

Comment: I see, I can skip this events on my side too, by this will spam event log on server anyway

Answer (score 0):

could you do this and from within the loop try to figure out what events you want to check

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry entry in EventLog1.Entries) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
}
```

Comment: I can skip this events on my side, by this will spam event log on server anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here's the deal with logs: they aim to be verbose. This 'problem' is an unfortunate side-effect of dealing with logs, but it is there by design! Imagine if anything that happens in the system could be ignored by the log. Wouldn't virus and malware makers love that (this sentence sounds so crummy, like saying the Terrorists Win)? Try not to call `GetEventLogs` in too tight of a loop, and you should be OK. You can also say something like

```
var myLogs =
    from item in collection
    skip SuccessAudit logs
    select logs I care about;
```

Comment: I see, I can skip this type of events, but I'll spam event log anyway. I was thinking that there is some way to prevent this from appearing if I have admin rights